# how to connect to wifi that has a encryption key, in terminal

Tags: terminal, wifi, iwconfig

I can connect to wifi

sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid 
sudo dhclient wlan0

but I don't know how to connect to encrypted wlan
so please tell me how to do that, if a wifi password is "abcdef"
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But this is only working with **WEP** encryption:

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid name key s:abcdef`

`sudo dhclient wlan0`

**WPA**

You will need to install `wpa-supplicant` (`sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant`)

After you have installed edit the `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

For example:

```
network={
            ssid="ssid_name"
             psk="abcdef"
}
```

And finally you can connect with commands:

`sudo wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext && sudo dhclient wlan0`

Comment: Oh my god!
That is definitely what I want.
Actually I don't know what WPA is, so I ignore the script about that.
So..Thank you so much, you are my life saver haha.